# What is the appropriate arithmetic type for a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, integer

In my code I have two char pointer, one to a string and the other as an error indicator for `strtoumax()` and `strtod()`. I am currently using the type `size_t` (aka unsigned long) to calculate the difference between them. Is there any type designed to specifically match pointer type size on every machine? Or do I have to check it myself with macros?

Comment: Why are you trying to calculate this difference?  Strictly speaking it's not defined to subtract or compare pointers which don't point into the same object.  (It's sort of like subtracting 123 Elm St. from 456 First Avenue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For pointer difference use `ptrdiff_t`. If you're just trying to store a pointer as an integer, use `uintptr_t` (or `intptr_t`).

Answer (score 3):

> In my code I have two char pointer, one to a string and the other as
> an error indicator for strtoumax() and strtod(). I am currently using
> the type size_t (aka unsigned long) to calculate the difference
> between them.

Don't do that.  If you want a pointer difference then compute a pointer difference:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// ...

ptrdiff_t difference = p2 - p1;
```

And note `ptrdiff_t`, which is the type of the result of a pointer difference.

If you want a difference in bytes instead of in units the size of the pointed-to type (including if the pointed-to type is incomplete, such as `void`) then first convert to pointers to `char`:

```
ptrdiff_t difference_in_bytes = (char *) p2 - (char *) p1;
```

(`char` is the smallest addressible unit of storage, but technically, it might be larger than 8 bits on some C implementations.  `CHAR_BIT` will help you figure that out if you're concerned about such cases.)

Do not compute a pointer difference by converting to integer and performing integer arithmetic, because although the behavior of that is defined (+/- signed integer overflow), the meaning of the result is not.

> Is there any type designed to specifically match pointer
> type size on every machine? Or do I have to check it myself with
> macros?

Yes.  In `stdint.h` there are definitions of `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`, which can support round-trip pointer to integer to pointer conversions without data loss.  But C does not define the meaning of the value resulting from converting a pointer to an integer, so these are best used as opaque types.

Comment: "Don't do that", I know, that's why I asked this question :)

Comment: Very good then, @Tenobaal.  But do note that my "that" is not about your particular choice of integer type, but rather about using integer arithmetic for this purpose at all.  I say this because to me the question reads as "which integer type should I use for the arithmetic?", to which I am answering "none".

Comment: Re “And note `ptrdiff_t`, which is an integer type large enough to accommodate any valid pointer difference.” The C standard does not say this. It just says `ptrdiff_t` is the type that is the result of subtracting two pointers. It does not guarantee the subtraction will not overflow. And consider its relationship to `size_t`. If `char *a` points near the beginning of the address space (near zero) and `char *b` points near the end (near `SIZE_MAX`), `a-b` and `b-a` cannot be both expressible in `ptrdiff_t` unless it is wider than `size_t`, which might not be feasible in some C implementations.

Comment: (Of course, the standard does not define subtraction of pointers into different objects, and it may be difficult to get an object large enough to cause this, but if an object larger than half the address space is possible, then this overflow can happen with behavior otherwise defined by the C standard.)

Comment: Acknowledged @EricPostpischil.  Your comments about subtraction of pointers into different objects is what I had in mind when I originally wrote about "valid" pointer differences, but you are right that C does not insist that `ptrdiff_t` be able to represent all differences between pointers into the same object.  I have revised to a simpler claim, rather than explain all the details in this answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger is there a defined way to get the number of characters consumed by `strtod()`?

Comment: Sure, @Tenobaal.  I assumed from the form of the question that you were already doing the appropriate thing.  You let `strtod()` give you the `endptr`, which points to the character following the last one used by `strtod()`. The pointer difference between that pointer and the beginning of the string, an integer of type `ptrdiff_t`, is the number of characters you are looking for.

Comment: I used `*errptr - startptr` instead of `errptr - startptr`, that is why I got a compiler error (char - char*). That's what caused my confusion, but knowing I was doing the right thing helped me a lot. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To store pointers as integers you can use `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`  declared in the header `<stdint.h>`.

From the C Standard (7.20.1.4 Integer types capable of holding object pointers)

> 1 The following type designates a signed integer type with the
> property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
> then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
> equal to the original pointer:

```
intptr_t
```

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
> property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
> then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare
> equal to the original pointer:

```
uintptr_t
```

> These types are optional.

To store difference between two pointers you can use `ptrdiff_t` declared in the header `<stddef.h>`.

Pay attention to that you may calculate difference between two pointers if they both point to elements of the same array or one past the last element. Otherwise you will get undefined behavior.